# windows 8 app for mobile device

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone

I am new to Windows Phone applications and Windows 8 Apps. All I know about windows 8 is the metro style and the news that it will run on the PCs, tablets and Phones as well.

I want to get started developing an App for an expected Windows 8 Phone Device. All the guideline I found for windows 8 is for developing the apps for windows 8 tablets or PCs (not phones). [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516) is a link for windows 8 SDK, I am looking at.

Should I start developing a regular windows 8 app (for tablet) assuming that it will run on the expected upcoming windows 8 phone device?

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has made very few announcements so far on the developer story for Windows Phone 8. What little news has been announced can be viewed in the Windows Phone Summit video here:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Windows-Phone/Summit

The only statement made so far regarding development across the two platforms is that applications developed using C# and Xaml will have "high compatibility" between Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8.

Windows Phone 8 is due out later this year so hopefully development tools aren't far off. If you want to get started right away I recommend you try your hand at developing a Windows 8 application using C# and Xaml. That should catch you up to speed and get you prepared for Windows Phone 8.

You can get started at http://dev.windows.com

Answer (score 1):

I think there is nothing really official about the development of applications windows phone 8 (except as regards the integration of the new features of future devices). Everything in internet indicates that one of the reasons that drove microsoft to update wp7 is precisely the desire to converge development for windows 8 with development for windows phone8. This convergence will be visual (for example the pivot layout will be characterized by a single page horizontally scrollable similar to windows 8 apps) and under the hood (with a kernel very similar). 
The enhanced hardware will perform more complex operations (thus tending toward user experience similar to pc).
What we also know that in some metro style app in actual microsoft store someone found comments in the source related to the integration of the app in windows phone 8.
What I can suggest then is to develop your app for windows 8. In all likelihood make the porting to Windows phone 8 will be simple (different sized images for backgrounds, different icons, but side code probably will not change anything).

Comment: http://alnurismail.com/maximizing-code-reuse-across-windows-8-and-windows-phone-apps/